# Meta-analysis: outlier search

Tags: r, outliers

I am doing a meta analysis using the packages **meta**, **metafor** and **metadat**. When doing a summarized analysis with subgroups and applying the function `find.outliers()`, it gives me different results than when I do the individual outlier search per subgroup. Does anyone know why that could be and what I can do about it?

To double check that the outlier search in the summarized analysis was correct, I tried running the outlier search individually per subgroup. And realized there were many fewer outliers identified this way, giving me a different summary estimate per subgroup.

Comment: Welcome to SO! I think we might need a combination of data and code to be helpful here, I can't even find the function `find.outliers()`. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example